# How to omit (remove) virtual environment (venv) from python coverage unit testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, coverage.py, python-venv

https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/source.html#source

My coverage is also including “venv” folder and I would like to exclude it
no matter what I do even with --include or omit nothing works

```
coverage run --omit /venv/* tests.py
```

This runs the test but still adds "venv" folder and dependencies and their % coverage

When I do

```
coverage run --include tests.py
```

To run only tests - it says

```
Nothing to do.
```

It is pretty annoying... can someone please help?

[image: Python Coverage Report]

Comment: Try `coverage run --include tests.py -m tests.py` instead

Comment: @Radek did you ever find a solution for this? I've tried every combination of the suggestions below and can't get the python files in the venv to be excluded.

Answer (score 19):

The help text for the `--omit` option says ([documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html#execution-coverage-run))

```
--omit=PAT1,PAT2,...  Omit files whose paths match one of these patterns.
                      Accepts shell-style wildcards, which must be quoted.
```

It will not work without quoting the wildcard, as bash will expand the wildcards  before handing the argument list to the coverage binary. Use single-quotes to avoid bash wildcard expansion.

To run my tests without getting coverage from any files within *venv/**:

```
$ coverage run --omit 'venv/*' -m unittest tests/*.py && coverage report -m
........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.023s

OK
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
ruterstop.py                 84      8    90%   177, 188, 191-197, 207
tests/test_ruterstop.py     108      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                       192      8    96%
```

If you usually use plain `python -m unittest` to run your tests you can of course omit the test target argument as well.

```
$ coverage run --omit 'venv/*' -m unittest
$ coverage report -m
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want to pass `--omit` each time when executing `coverage` you can define following in `.coveragerc` or in `pyproject.toml`. Example for `.coveragerc`:

```
# .coveragerc file content
[run]
omit = [
  .venv/*
  tests/*
]
```

Example for `pyproject.toml`:

```
# pyproject.toml file content
[tool.coverage.run]
omit = [
    "tests/*",
    ".venv/*",
]
```

Comment: I put the snippet into `pyproject.toml` and still have `.venv` included. Any idea why?

Comment: > If coverage.py is installed with the toml extra (pip install coverage[toml]), it will automatically read from “pyproject.toml”. Configuration must be within the [tool.coverage] section, for example, [tool.coverage.run].

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
coverage run --omit /venv/* tests.py
```

omits coverage from `/venv` (ie: `venv` is off of root).

You should instead try a relative directory like:

```
coverage run --omit venv tests.py
```

Comment: I did the 2nd command like you said, got this error: Can't find '__main__' module in 'venv/include'

Comment: It ran, but still have venv there in the report, I have deleted .coverage file and ran the command again no luck still venv in the report.

Comment: Sorry, I use [pytest-cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/) to run my coverage tests.

Comment: Have installed pytest-cov, what is the command to run it to see the report - py.test --cov=myproj tests/ - I do not have any folder in my project - so how would that look like?

Comment: Found it, same problem, just like other coverage - it is using .coveragerc file where you have globs - tried everything also via help - does not work - I have no folders in the project directory only venv, if I put that file glob [run] omit in the file it says can't read from the file, I have no idea how to make it work, commands or file globs - nothing works. Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` for `/venv/` and it will eliminate all files within your virtual environment.

`coverage run tests.py && coverage report --omit=*/venv/*`