# Flake8 times out on circle-ci

Tags: python, circleci, flake8

We have a `flake8` build stage in our `circle-ci` workflow, and more often than not this step fails due to timeout:

```
Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

At the same time, this same stage runs quite ok locally on our macbooks:

```
% time make lint
poetry run black  .
All done! ✨  ✨
226 files left unchanged.
isort -y
Skipped 2 files
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project poetry run flake8 --show-source
0
make lint  44.00s user 4.90s system 102% cpu 47.810 total
```

We tried to debug the issue by adding the `-vv` flag to `flake8` thinking we would get some plugin name that takes too long, but we don't even have the timestamps in the log:

```
flake8.processor          ForkPoolWorker-31   1004 WARNING  Plugin requested optional parameter "visitor" but this is not an available parameter.
flake8.processor          ForkPoolWorker-8   1080 WARNING  Plugin requested optional parameter "visitor" but this is not an available parameter.
flake8.bugbear            ForkPoolWorker-26   1082 INFO     Optional warning B950 not present in selected warnings: ['E', 'F', 'W', 'C90']. Not firing it at all.
```

Are there any known reasons why `flake8` would freeze on CircleCI? How can one debug the issue?

Comment: if limiting the cores fixed the problem it's possible that the multiprocessing module is reporting more cores than are available and it's context-switching to death - current flake8 maintainer

Answer (score 2):

When using a virtual-environment such as `venv` you should ignore the folder in the `[flake8]`-config (that's what happened to me). Assuming you are creating a virtualenv with `virtualenv .venv` it would look like this:

```
[flake8]
exclude = .venv
```

The same was for my coverage which was fixed by adding an `omit` to that config (solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68755029/7132596)):

```
# pyproject.toml file content
[tool.coverage.run]
omit = [
    "tests/*",
    ".venv/*",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, the solution we seem to have found was to limit the number of cores running flake8:

`.flake8`

```
[flake8]
...
jobs = 6
```

Not sure it is the correct solution, but there you go. I will accept a better solution if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced a timeout in circle-ci only, but it was due to the specific way dependencies are installed on the pipeline, creating a .venv folder which was not excluded in flake8 configuration.

The -v option helped me to notice the huge amount of files flkae8 was analyzing.